# System.UnexpectedException: Got an unexpected error in callout : null

Tags: java, flex3, oracle-apex

i am calling apex web service from flex using execute() method and iam passing objects as a parameter and i am getting error like this

```
Error is (com.salesforce.results::Fault)#0
  context = (null)
  detail = (null)
  faultcode = "soapenv:Client"
  faultstring = "System.UnexpectedException: Got an unexpected error in callout : null. Contact support with error ID: 1835527547-14083 (-677061709)
```

How to solve this ....

Answer (score 0):

Any time you see the text to contact support and an error ID, it was actually a bug in Salefsorce's code and there's nothing you can really do to work around it.

The best you can do is contact their support team and log a ticket.  A lot of times they can find a suitable workaround that'll work in the meantime.